# php class variables interaction

Tags: php, class, oop, var

That's the problem, how can I call a class variable from a class function? Let me explain better:

```
    <?php

class Mine
{

    private $g = 'gg';
    const COSTANTE = 'valo';

    public static function sayHello()
    {
        echo self::COSTANTE;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $this->g;
    }
}
$h = new Mine();
$h->sayHello();
$h::sayHello();
?>
```

when I run this, it just print the constant COSTANTE.... Why it doesn't print the variable g?

Comment: You can't use non-static properties in static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on error reporting ( [error_reporting ( E_ALL );](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) ), and you should receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

The pseudo-variable `$this` is a reference to the calling object, and is available from within an object context.

`self` is used to access the current class, since static functions can be called without the actual object instance, when the method is called statically `$this` reference does not exists.

A method declared as `static` can be accessed with an instantiated class object ( but it is always executed in a static context ), a property declared as `static` cannot.

Answer (score 1):

`valo` will be printed but `gg` and will not.
The issue is because you have used a non-static variable in a static method which will raise a FATAL error and will stop execution. This is because there is no object context.

Its not encouraged to use non-static variable inside static methods but, in case you need to use one, you have to create an object first.

Your `sayHello` function will be something like

```
public static function sayHello()
{
    echo self::COSTANTE;
    echo '<br>';
    $mineObject = new Mine;
    echo $mineObject->g;
}
```

I will also suggest keep error reporting and display errors ON while developing so that you can have a better idea of whats happening out there.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'ON');
```